# Change the position of the <li> using a display:flex not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the position of the "li" using a display:flex , but it is not working. How to solve this problem?

```css
.testul li {
    display: flex;
    flexible direction: column;
    } 
    
    .test ul li: nth child (1) {
    blue background;
    order: 2;
    }
 .test ul li: nth child (2) {
    blue background;
    order: 1;
    }
```

```html
<div class = "test">
    <ul class = "rgsize small" style = "display: block;">
    
    <li class = "attr-conf -">
    <a href = "" class = "attr-cls attr-cls-230">
    Select the test</a>
    </li>
    
    <li class = "attr-conf-587" style = "display: list item;">
    <a href = "" class = "attr-cls attr-cls-230 acmtlist">
    test</a>
    </li>
    
    <li class = "attr-conf-563" style = "display: list item;">
    <a href = "" class = "attr-cls attr-cls-230">test</a>
    </li>
    
    <li class = "attr-conf-566" style = "display: list item;">
    <a href = "javascript: void (0);" class="attr-cls attr-cls-230">
    test</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your CSS selectors are invalid.

Comment: CSS Flexbox does not recognize flexible direction. Update it with `flex-direction: column;`

Comment: The majority of the CSS is syntactically erroneous. The fundamental pattern isn't even adhered to: `ul test` not `testul`, `background: blue` not `blue background`,`'flex-direction: column` not `flexible direction: column`. If you wanted the `<li>` to be positioned left to right then apply all flex properties to `<ul>` not `<li>` and `flex-direction: row` is what you probably wanted (although not completely clear since your question lacks any relevant and/or specific info). Moreover the on the `<li>` should be `style="display: list-item"` but even so it is redundant because  it is default.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display each `li` side by side, then you need to consider the `ul` as the container, so you'll have to do something like:

```css
.test ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <ul class="rgsize small">

    <li class="attr-conf -">
      <a href="" class="attr-cls attr-cls-230">
    Select the test</a>
    </li>

    <li class="attr-conf-587" style="display: list item;">
      <a href="" class="attr-cls attr-cls-230 acmtlist">
    test</a>
    </li>

    <li class="attr-conf-563" style="display: list item;">
      <a href="" class="attr-cls attr-cls-230">test</a>
    </li>

    <li class="attr-conf-566" style="display: list item;">
      <a href="javascript: void (0);" class="attr-cls attr-cls-230">
    test</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Furthermore, you have some syntax errors in your CSS, such as a missing space `.testul li` and wrong order `blue background;` (should be `background: blue;`).

Answer (score 0):

For example, i want to change the position of the "li" using css

```
 <li class="attr-conf-563" style="display: list item;">
      <a href="" class="attr-cls attr-cls-230">test2</a>
    </li>

    <li class="attr-conf-566" style="display: list item;">
      <a href="javascript: void (0);" class="attr-cls attr-cls-230">
    test1</a>
    </li>
```

Change the "test1" to "test2"

Comment: Remove the answer and post it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the effect you are trying to get

```css
  .test > ul {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }

      .test ul li:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: blue;
        order: 2;
      }
      .test ul li {
        padding: 20px;
        list-style: none;
      }
```